# Speech Recognition in C# without using windows' speech recognition

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition

I know the first comment will be that am duplicating previous threads, but the codes I found (from MSDN) uses window's speech recognition... I'm doing my graduation project and speech recognition is part of it! and I cant include this code,I have to try and do it from scratch, am doing some researches about it and I would be really thankful if someone have already done this and can give me a link for a paper or a code I can benefit from !

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can't use the Windows code then surely you can't use anyone else's (or am I missing something?)

Comment: lol no am not gonna use it! esp. that I need for a different language! but I just want to understand more about it :)

Comment: What an absolute silly project requirement to force you to reinvent the wheel (and your wheel will be a bad wheel at that) instead of doing something useful with the wheel.

Comment: couldn't agree more! 
I have a meeting with him tomorrow and I will try my best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Microsoft Server Speech Platform 10.1 (SR and TTS in 26 languages)**

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24003

**The basic operations that speech recognition applications perform:**

1. Starting the speech recognizer.
2. Creating a recognition grammar.
3. Loading the grammar into a speech recognizer.
4. Registering for speech recognition event notification.
5. Creating a handler for the speech recognition event.

**Language Packs**

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3971

**Runtime Download**

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24974

These libraries could, at least, give you a starter to understand the makeup of the interfaces, and a starter of the core/base code to copy/steal or emulate ;)

**There's also this paper:**

http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~mohri/pub/hbka.pdf

Best of Luck!

Comment: I do ot envy the task ahead of you. ;)

Comment: Lol thanks for the answer! my browser is full of tabs and downloaded slides right now! 
and for the comment...me neither ! :(

Comment: Files can't be downloaded

Answer (score 1):

Writing the code that implements the basic recognition algorithm (**Hidden Markov Model** based recognizers are the norm these days) is only part of your challenge. Virtually every speech recognition system is **trained on actual speech data**, so you also have to identify a corpus (collection of audio files and transcriptions) to train your mathematical models.

Have a look at the open source [Sphinx speech recognizer](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) (and related tools) from CMU if you are still interested in doing it all by yourself.